# Bust cache after content change with Sanity?

Tags: caching, next.js, vercel, sanity

I'm using Sanity as a CMS and Next JS as my frontend. I’d like my site to be able to handle a reasonable amount of traffic so I think I need some caching.

However if an editor makes a change to the content in Sanity and then refreshes the live site they will expect to see the change right away. Is there a way to achieve both?

Below is my Next JS component. I had to add `force-dynamic` to prevent the page from being statically generated, otherwise the content doesn't update until re-deployed.

I also had to set `useCdn: false` for editors to see their changes immediately, however according to the docs this makes the API calls slower and more expensive:
https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-cdn-configuration

```
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";

const client = createClient({
  projectId: 'process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID',
  dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET,
  apiVersion: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_V,
  useCdn: false,
});

export default async function Home() {
  const res = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "posts"] {
    _id,
    name
  }`,
  );
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)}
    </div>
  );
}

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

Comment: Keep your code as is. Just pass the cache property next to the query. For example, client.fetch(query, {cache: 'no-store'} ). I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I can't even get the content to revalidate when the sanity webhook fires - so you're saying if the useCdn is set to false and you do a change in sanity, your webhook runs and the content changes? I'd be happy with that, but as i said our content doesn't even change at this point. Do i need dynamic = "force-dynamic' for that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a good solution but it does seem to work.

Set a cookie when a user logs in to identify them as an Editor:
`document.cookie = "sanityRole=Editor; path=/";`

Then check for the cookie and don't use the CDN if its detected.

One downside is if the editor makes a change on one browser or device but looks on another without also logging in then they'll still hit the CDN.

An even better solution would be to bust the cache when the content changes so that all users see the latest data, but not sure if thats possible.

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { createClient } from "next-sanity";

export default async function Home() {

  const userIsEditor: boolean =
    cookies()
      .getAll()
      .find((c) => c.name === "sanityRole")?.value === "Editor";
  
  const client = createClient({
    projectId: 'process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID',
    dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET,
    apiVersion: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_API_V,
    useCdn: !userIsEditor,
  });

  const res = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "posts"] {
      _id,
      name
    }`,
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)}
    </div>
  );
}

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

Answer (score 1):

I've also struggled with caching with next (app directory) and Sanity. Ideally it caches until there's a change, then invalidates the content. I've tried using Sanity webhooks with Next cache tags to invalidate, without success. I've even had caching issues in dev mode...sometimes the content refuses to update, other times updates instantly or on the second page load. What I've settled on (for now) is re-deploying the site after making content changes. It works for smaller sites that don't change often. I use this Sanity plugin to add a deploy button to the CMS Dashboard:

https://www.sanity.io/plugins/vercel-deploy